# how can I sort a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have  coordinates of some points$(x,y)$, that I want to sort them,at the first by $y$
coordinates and second sort $x$ coordinates between those points that have equal $y$ coordinate.
Is there anyone know any function in matlab about it?
I examined it by $SORT$ function, but this function just sort each column of matrix.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sortrows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) should be what you are looking for.

Though you may need to swap $x$ and $y$ first, or use the optional argument to tell it which column to base the sort first.

(BTW, the kind of ordering you are looking for is called "[lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)"; that may help you do more searches on the internet.)